# unit of measurement in android that replaces em in html?

Tags: android, xml

In Html we could use em, and it would adjust the size and format of everything to the appropriate size despite Resolution. Does android have a unit of measurement that adjusts views to its appropriate sizes and formats despite the different screen resolutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android uses scalable points or SP

here is a sample

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sample Text - 26sp"
        android:textSize="26sp" />
```

[Reference](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-user-interface-design-basic-font-sizes--mobile-11194)

Comment: can it apply to options like android:layout_height and android:layout_marginTop?

Comment: It should be added that SP scales based on user's selected font size. There are Density Pixes(DP). DP = SP on default font size, but they don't scale based on font size.
SP should be used for text, and DP is better for margins, element sizes etc.

Answer (score 2):

you can normally use **dp,sp,** [for ref](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension)

Answer (score 2):

You normally use **dp** for View sizes.
And **sp** for font sizes.